# How can I create a recovery drive for arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot

I have a full arch system but I want to reinstall windows (without deleting arch Linux, but if I have my system on a USB I can just use that).

Comment: Please clarify what a "recovery drive" means for for you. Essentially a bootable copy of your existing OS environment migrated onto USB? A tool for accessing and fixing a broken LinuxOS installation (a live USB of Arch Linux should work for that)? A compressed disk image of your existing installation + tools to rewrite it back to system disk? Something else? Or are you asking how to create a *Windows* installation/recovery drive *using Linux*?

Answer (score 0):

First, resize your Arch install by using a tool like GParted, *disk/c*disk, etc. I would just use GParted Live on a USB and resize the disk.
After that, install Windows to the blank space. Just download an image (you can get one from the [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)), flash it using DD, Etcher, UNetbootin, etc. and install to "Unallocated Space".

Answer (score -1):

Requirements for installing Arch Linux: A x86_64 (i.e. 64 bit) well matched machine.

- Step 1: Download the ISO.
- Step 2: Create a live USB of Arch Linux.
- Step 3: Boot from the live USB.
- Step 4: Partitioning the disks.
- Step 4: Creating filesystem.
- Step 5: Installation.
- Step 6: Configuring the system.

Comment: Please note that the OP asked how to install _Windows_, not Arch Linux.